# Having issues with python skipping try statements

Tags: python, if-statement, except

I am working on a Python program that is centered around randomly using a function with a few fall backs. For some reason when the program enters the function labeled auto_swipe it does not attempt any of the try statements and slips into the last exception. I have tried using print statements to see if the the try statements pass and I get no output.

Here is the code:

```
def auto_swipe(self):
    from random import random
    while True:
        sleep(0.5)
        try:
            rand = random()
            if rand < .73:
                self.like()

            else:
                self.dislike()

        except Exception:
            try:
                self.close_popup()
            except Exception:
                self.close_match()
```

Comment: Why are you doing imports inside a function?

Comment: Do you know what exception(s) are being raised?

Comment: Do you have like, dislike and close_popup functions defined? As much I can check, rand is generating values that are going for `if-else` block. If you dont't have any of these 3 functions defined, then it will go to self.close_match()

Comment: I am importing the functions because I plan on reusing them throughout the program once I fix this system and yes all of the functions are defined.